# Find and extract <a href> link from string in python

Tags: python, html, regex, find

I'm Using outlook lib for work with emails. I receive mail body like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional //EN"><html><head=

>

<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8"><t=

itle>Facebook</title><style>@media all and (max-width: 480px){*[class].ib_t=

{min-width:100% !important}*[class].ib_row{display:block !important}*[class=

].ib_ext{display:block !important;padding:10px 0 5px 0;vertical-align:top !=

important;width:100% !important}*[class].ib_img,*[class].ib_mid{vertical-al=

ign:top !important}*[class].mb_blk{display:block !important;padding-bottom:=

10px;width:100% !important}*[class].mb_hide{display:none !important}*[class=

].mb_inl{display:inline !important}}.d_mb_show{display:none}.d_mb_show_cent=

er{display:table;margin:auto}@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480p=

x){.d_mb_hide{display:none !important}.d_mb_show{display:block !important}}=

.mb_text h1,.mb_text h2,.mb_text h3,.mb_text h4,.mb_text h5,.mb_text h6{lin=

e-height:normal}.mb_work_text h1{font-size:18px;line-height:normal;margin-t=

op:4px}.mb_work_text h2,.mb_work_text h3{font-size:16px;line-height:normal;=

margin-top:4px}.mb_work_text h4,.mb_work_text h5,.mb_work_text h6{font-size=

:14px;line-height:normal}.mb_work_text a{color:#1270e9}.mb_work_text p{marg=

in-top:4px}</style></head><body style=3D"margin:0;padding:0;" dir=3D"ltr" b=

gcolor=3D"#ffffff"><table border=3D"0" width=3D"100%;" cellspacing=3D"0" ce=

llpadding=3D"0" id=3D"email_table" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr>=

<td id=3D"email_content" style=3D"font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Luci=

da Grande,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;background:#ffffff;"><table borde=

r=3D"0" width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-=

collapse:collapse;"><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"20" style=3D"line-height:2=

0px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td height=3D"1" colspan=3D"3" styl=

e=3D"line-height:1px;"></td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" wid=

th=3D"430" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:col=

lapse;margin:0 auto 0 auto;"><tr><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" width=

=3D"430px" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:col=

lapse;margin:0 auto 0 auto;width:430px;"><tr style=3D""><td width=3D"15" st=

yle=3D"display:block;width:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><ta=

ble border=3D"0" width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=

=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D""><img src=3D"https://stati=

c.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yv/r/ri-arh5nIkG.png" width=3D"430" style=3D"bor=

der:0;width:430px;"></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"lin=

e-height:30px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><table bor=

der=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:coll=

apse;"><tr><td width=3D"30" style=3D"display:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp=

;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpaddin=

g=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D""><p style=3D"=

padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#000000;font-size:25px;">Welcome=

 to Instagram, sepoi7936</p><p style=3D"padding:0;margin:0;text-align:cente=

r;color:#565a5c;font-size:18px;">First, please confirm your email address. =

If you're ever locked out of your account, this will help us get you back i=

n.</p></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-height:30px;=

" colspan=3D"1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><a href=3D"https://insta=

gram.com/accounts/confirm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ=

/?app_redirect=3DFalse" style=3D"color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;display=

:block;width:370px;"><table border=3D"0" width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" c=

ellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D"borde=

r-collapse:collapse;border-radius:3px;text-align:center;display:block;borde=

r:solid 1px #009fdf;padding:10px 16px 14px 16px;margin:0 2px 0 auto;min-wid=

th:80px;background-color:#47A2EA;"><a href=3D"https://instagram.com/account=

s/confirm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=

=3DFalse" style=3D"color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;display:block;"><cent=

er><font size=3D"3"><span style=3D"font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Rob=

oto,Arial,sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:mid=

dle;color:#fdfdfd;font-size:16px;line-height:16px;">Confirm&nbsp;your&nbsp;=

email&nbsp;address</span></font></center></a></td></tr></table></a></td></t=

r><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"3=

">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D"border-top:solid 1px #c8c8c8;"></td></tr=

></table></td><td width=3D"30" style=3D"display:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&n=

bsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"25" styl=

e=3D"line-height:25px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td widt=

h=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;width:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><t=

r style=3D""><td width=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;width:15px;">&nbsp;&nb=

sp;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" width=3D"100%" cellspacing=

=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=

=3D""><img src=3D"https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yg/r/zACQd8KtsK7.=

png" width=3D"430" style=3D"border:0;width:430px;"></td></tr><tr style=3D""=

><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></t=

r><tr><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0=

" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td width=3D"30" style=3D"display=

:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><table border=3D"=

0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;">=

<tr><td style=3D""><p style=3D"padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#=

000000;font-size:25px;">Choose What You See</p><p style=3D"padding:0;margin=

:0;text-align:center;color:#565a5c;font-size:18px;">Following someone means=

 you'll see the photos and videos they post. The more accounts you follow, =

the more great stuff you'll see in your feed. Follow your friends or people=

 who share your interests.</p></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" st=

yle=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D"">=

<a href=3D"https://instagram.com/accounts/confirm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aG=

RhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse" style=3D"color:#3b5998;text=

-decoration:none;display:block;width:370px;"><table border=3D"0" width=3D"1=

00%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;=

"><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;border-radius:3px;text-align:ce=

nter;display:block;border:solid 1px #009fdf;padding:10px 16px 14px 16px;mar=

gin:0 2px 0 auto;min-width:80px;background-color:#47A2EA;"><a href=3D"https=

://instagram.com/accounts/confirm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb2=

9rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse" style=3D"color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none=

;display:block;"><center><font size=3D"3"><span style=3D"font-family:Helvet=

ica Neue,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;font-weight:b=

old;vertical-align:middle;color:#fdfdfd;font-size:16px;line-height:16px;">F=

ind&nbsp;People&nbsp;to&nbsp;Follow</span></font></center></a></td></tr></t=

able></a></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-height:30=

px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D"border-top:solid 1px #c=

8c8c8;"></td></tr></table></td><td width=3D"30" style=3D"display:block;widt=

h:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td h=

eight=3D"25" style=3D"line-height:25px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr></ta=

ble></td><td width=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;width:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&=

nbsp;</td></tr><tr style=3D""><td width=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;width=

:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" width=3D"=

100%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse=

;"><tr><td style=3D""><img src=3D"https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y=

4/r/twHu0ANul9l.png" width=3D"430" style=3D"border:0;width:430px;"></td></t=

r><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"3=

">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" =

cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td width=3D"30" =

style=3D"display:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><=

table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-coll=

apse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D""><p style=3D"padding:0;margin:0;text-alig=

n:center;color:#000000;font-size:25px;">Express Yourself</p><p style=3D"pad=

ding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#565a5c;font-size:18px;">Share your=

 perspective by capturing and sharing photos and videos from your day, whet=

her it's your morning routine or the trip of a lifetime. Instagram's free f=

ilters and tools make it easy to express yourself in new ways.</p></td></tr=

><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"1"=

>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><a href=3D"https://instagram.com/accoun=

ts/confirm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=

=3DFalse" style=3D"color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;display:block;width:3=

70px;"><table border=3D"0" width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"=

0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse:col=

lapse;border-radius:3px;text-align:center;display:block;border:solid 1px #0=

09fdf;padding:10px 16px 14px 16px;margin:0 2px 0 auto;min-width:80px;backgr=

ound-color:#47A2EA;"><a href=3D"https://instagram.com/accounts/confirm_emai=

l/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse" style=

=3D"color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;display:block;"><center><font size=

=3D"3"><span style=3D"font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,san=

s-serif;white-space:nowrap;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:middle;color:#fd=

fdfd;font-size:16px;line-height:16px;">Open&nbsp;Instagram</span></font></c=

enter></a></td></tr></table></a></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" =

style=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D"=

border-top:solid 1px #c8c8c8;"></td></tr></table></td><td width=3D"30" styl=

e=3D"display:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></=

tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"25" style=3D"line-height:25px;" colspan=3D"=

3">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;wid=

th:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr style=3D""><td width=3D"15" style=

=3D"display:block;width:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><table=

 border=3D"0" width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"b=

order-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D""><img src=3D"https://static.xx.=

fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yC/r/QbsnSndHS4m.png" width=3D"430" style=3D"border:0=

;width:430px;"></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-hei=

ght:30px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><table border=

=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collaps=

e;"><tr><td width=3D"30" style=3D"display:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&n=

bsp;</td><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=

=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D""><p style=3D"p=

adding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#000000;font-size:25px;">Explore =

Your Interests</p><p style=3D"padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#5=

65a5c;font-size:18px;">Visit the Explore tab to find photos and videos from=

 accounts you're not following yet. We'll show you posts you might like, ba=

sed on your interests and activity on Instagram. You can also find new acco=

unts to follow, so you'll see their posts in your feed.</p></td></tr><tr st=

yle=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"1">&nbsp;=

</td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><a href=3D"https://instagram.com/accounts/conf=

irm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse=

" style=3D"color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;display:block;width:370px;"><=

table border=3D"0" width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=

=3D"border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse:collapse;bo=

rder-radius:3px;text-align:center;display:block;border:solid 1px #009fdf;pa=

dding:10px 16px 14px 16px;margin:0 2px 0 auto;min-width:80px;background-col=

or:#47A2EA;"><a href=3D"https://instagram.com/accounts/confirm_email/Ufsti1=

rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse" style=3D"color=

:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;display:block;"><center><font size=3D"3"><spa=

n style=3D"font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;whi=

te-space:nowrap;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:middle;color:#fdfdfd;font-s=

ize:16px;line-height:16px;">Visit&nbsp;Explore</span></font></center></a></=

td></tr></table></a></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"30" style=3D"lin=

e-height:30px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=3D"border-top:s=

olid 1px #c8c8c8;"></td></tr></table></td><td width=3D"30" style=3D"display=

:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr style=

=3D""><td height=3D"25" style=3D"line-height:25px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</t=

d></tr></table></td><td width=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;width:15px;">&n=

bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;width=

:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style=3D""><p style=3D"padding:0;margin:=

0;text-align:center;color:#565a5c;font-size:18px;">Clicking any of the link=

s above will confirm nimaazhdari12@outlook.com on Instagram.</p></td><td wi=

dth=3D"15" style=3D"display:block;width:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>=

</table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td style=3D""><table border=3D"0" =

width=3D"430px" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" style=3D"border-collaps=

e:collapse;margin:0 auto 0 auto;width:430px;"><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"=

30" style=3D"line-height:30px;" colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width=

=3D"30" style=3D"display:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td styl=

e=3D""><div style=3D"color:#abadae;font-size:12px;margin:0 auto 5px auto;">=

=C2=A9 Instagram, 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, CA 94022</div><div style=3D"col=

or:#abadae;font-size:12px;margin:0 auto 5px auto;">This message was sent to=

 <a style=3D"color:#abadae;text-decoration:underline;">nimaazhdari12@outloo=

k.com</a> and intended for sepoi7936. Instagram sends updates like this to =

help you keep up with the latest on Instagram. You can unsubscribe from the=

se updates, or remove your email if this isn't your Instagram account. <a h=

ref=3D"https://instagram.com/emails/unsubscribe/tutorial?user_id=3D56847734=

80&amp;sig=3DAU_lxK13iCXRWi8x" style=3D"color:#abadae;text-decoration:under=

line;">Unsubscribe</a> or <a href=3D"https://instagram.com/accounts/remove/=

report_wrong_email/2m0kfag/4nf-865fa936d95b370febb99c189175d18a/vVT7r6CQ/bm=

ltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/" style=3D"color:#abadae;text-decoration:u=

nderline;">remove your email</a> from this account.<br></div></td><td width=

=3D"30" style=3D"display:block;width:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></t=

able></td></tr><tr style=3D""><td height=3D"20" style=3D"line-height:20px;"=

 colspan=3D"3">&nbsp;</td></tr></table><span style=3D""><img src=3D"https:/=

/www.facebook.com/email_open_log_pic.php?mid=3DHMjY0NTExNjE1Om5pbWFhemhkYXJ=

pMTJAb3V0bG9vay5jb206ODU5" style=3D"border:0;width:1px;height:1px;"></span>=

</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

i need to extract confirmation instagram link for open and confirm it automatically. link like this :

```
https://instagram.com/accounts/confirm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=False
```

it is repeated two or three times.
how can i find just one of them?

i use some regex 
urlmaker:

```
    URL_REGEX = r"""(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\b/?(?!@)))"""

import urlmarker
import re
re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX,mystring)
```

but not take the link completely.

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4954037) on parsing html with regex (in short: don't do it!).

Comment: You might want to decode that [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) before even trying to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
This is an html parser, that will make it easy to find precise tags.
Instantiate a `BeautifulSoup` object with your html code as argument.
Then use its `find_all` method to find the hyperlink tags (`<a>` becomes `"a"`).

The tags' attributes can be got through the dict syntax, so the url will be found at `tag['href']`.

```
import bs4

html = """<body>...</body>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
aTags = soup.find_all("a")

urls = [tag['href'] for tag in aTags if 'href' in tag.attrs and "https://instagram.com" in tag['href']]
```

For clarity, here is the comprehension in its expanded form:

```
urls = []
for tag in aTages:
    if 'href' in tag.attrs and "https://instagram.com" in tag['href']:
        urls.append(tag)
```

Comment: @NimaAzhdari `bs4` is the name under which BeautifulSoup is imported. Are you sure you installed it right? You should use pip for this. Open a terminal and run `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: i have installed bs4 lib. but got this error : --- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/11/Desktop/mailout.py", line 11, in <module>
    urls = [tag['href'] for tag in aTags if tag['href'].startswith("https://instagram.com")]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: @NimaAzhdari Please check the last edit. I tried it, now it works as exepected.

Comment: yep tnx for your concern. that error is gone. but i have got other error and force to change the "soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(x)" to "soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(x,"lxml")" . when i run these codes , print urls = [ ] , it is null and when i print soup i see a lot of body code and <a href> link is cut . there it is -> :https://instagram.com/accounts/confirm_email/Ufsti1=' ---- but it must be like this : https://instagram.com/accounts/confirm_email/Ufsti1rj/bmltYWF6aGRhcmkxMkBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ/?app_redirect=False

Comment: @NimaAzhdari Indeed, that's because the url contains equal signs... I'm looking for a fix.

Comment: i think i figure out something , the confirm instagram link is always static to specific count. i received a new confirmation email for new username, and it is about 108 character.same as before. you think can count a number of character in this situation. maybe there is the simplest way.

Comment: I could handle it and finally your code is worked ;) I changed the Decode value to "true" in mail library message.py file .all "=" signs are removed.  I wrote the other code that is worked by length (108 character) but yours is better. i just need a another thing, your code achieve all link , and confirm link is repeated many times. possible to get it once ? i can not understand what "tag['href'] " is and why is it before "for" ? i know the for loop statement but can't change it to grab one link and break the loop.

Comment: @NimaAzhdari I edited my post so as to show you the expanded version of the `for` loop. `'href'` is one of the attributes of the `<a>` tag in html, and it's the attribute that holds the url. If `tag` is a BeautifulSoup tag object, its `attrs` member holds the attributes of its html equivalent, so if `href` is in `tag.attrs`, then I want to get its value, that is, `tag.attrs['href']`. `tag['href']` is a shorthand for `tag.attrs['href']`.

Comment: thank you so much , just please edit it to urls=tag.attrs['href'] , because 'tag' get all attributes like style: color, font,... . and one more question. how could you be such a professional programmer in python ? what is your source ? and there are any jobs that is needed just python ? something like this is too hared than being software developer or network senior .

Comment: @NimaAzhdari Yeah you seem to be right... To be honnest, I have been using BeautifulSoup for only two weeks, and in only one single small project (and it turned out it's wonderful!). As for how I know Python... Well, I started coding four or so years ago, and I learnt Python nearly three years ago. I liked it, and I made a lot of projects with it, from small to less small. I read a lot on StackOverflow, because I find a lot of things very interesting and surprising (did you know the `while`-`else` syntax??), and so I signed up and tried to explain things I knew, and learnt new things as well.

Comment: @NimaAzhdari In short: be curious!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148301/discussion-between-nima-azhdari-and-right-leg).